# how to do Routes.IgnoreRoute in web api project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my web api project Application_Start() method, I am doing the following to allow for elmah.axd

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
```

But that requires a dependency on System.Web.Mvc and related dll's like System.Web.WebPages that I don't really want in my web api project. Is there a way to get the IgnoreRoutes functionality without bringing in all those dll's?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do? If you web host (meaning you are in ASP.NET runtime) Web API there is no problem in referencing System.Web (Routing is *not* part of MVC it's part of core ASP.NET), and if you use self host, well that can't serve static files anyway unless you serve them as stream from controllers..

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for IgnoreRoutes in ASP.NET Web API's routing system unfortunately. However, if the app is being hosted in ASP.NET (as opposed to being hosted as a SelfHost app), you can still add an IgnoreRoute to the RouteTable (just as you would in MVC).

Answer (score 0):

WebApi 2.1 now implements a version of the IgnoreRoute extension method

```
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah", "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Under the hood this creates a System.Web.Http.Routing.StopRoutingHandler which is then [remapped](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/0ee98f84b41b6bef6bde6945e2797de9dac7d48a/src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/Routing/HttpRouteExtensions.cs) to a System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler anyway.

However under MVC4 WebApi1 (supported by mono) I couldn't work around this, but others should get away with:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ignore",
            routeTemplate: "{resource}.asp/{*pathInfo}",
            handler: new System.Web.Http.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()
);
```